# Alternatives to libQGLViewer?

Tags: c++, opengl, toolkit

I'm looking for a C++ toolkit alternative to libQGLViewer, which is open source and supports both Linux/MacOSX platforms for interactive 3D visualisation. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OGRE: http://www.ogre3d.org
OpenSceneGraph: http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg

IMHO OpenSceneGraph is easier to use for novice, but OGRE is much better engineered for high quality graphics.